# Inequality with measure and weight

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(M, \mu)$ be a measure space and $g\in L_{loc}^{1}(M)$ be a positive non-zero function. How can one show that for $f$ measurable and $a>0$ $$\mu\left\{|f|> \frac{1}{a}\right\}\leq a^{2}\frac{\int_{M}{f^{2}gd\mu}}{\int_{M}{gd\mu}}?$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Take $M = [0,2]$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. Then if $g=1$ and $f = C/a$ with $1<C<\sqrt{2}$, we have $\int g\, d\mu = 2$ and $\int f^2g\, d\mu = 2C^2/a^2$. So
$$2 = \mu\left\lbrace |f|>1/a\right\rbrace > a^2 \frac{\int f^2g\, d\mu}{\int g\, d\mu}= C^2.$$